# Setup /MyStaticSite on a Drupal 7 installation

Tags: apache, drupal, mod-rewrite, drupal-7

I have a drupal installation at http://myserver.com and I'd like to serve an old micro-site that I have from http://myserver.com/MyStaticSite. For the record, this site has a ton of HTML pages and images I had downloaded in the past with wget.

How would be the correct way to do that in Drupal? Do I need some specific rewrite recipe? Maybe some rule like

> when you get /MyStaticSite/X -> /sites/default/files/MyStaticSite/X

?

Answer (score 0):

If `MyStaticSite` is a folder in your root directory, you don't need to do anything, standard Drupal `.htaccess` will find it and serve content from that folder. Just be aware that if `MyStaticSite` is also a path in your Drupal namespace, your real folder will override it and you'll have no access to the Drupal's path. If `MyStaticSite` happens to be the name of a Drupal root's subdirectory (e.g. `scripts` or `modules`), you have a problem. You may well copy your microsite's content in the Drupal subdirectory (provided that none of your file names conflicts with Drupal's ones), but you will have a hard time in updating Drupal when needed.